# If a Markov chain depends on its two previous states?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm currently working on a project related to the Markov chain, but this Markov chain is non-standard, $X_t$ depends on its two previous states $X_{t-2}, X_{t-1}$. In a standard Markov chain, $X_t$ only depends on its previous state $X_{t-1}$, and we can express $X_t$ easily.

How to start analyzing if a state $X_t$ depends on its two previous states $X_{t-2}, X_{t-1}$. Can this non-standard Markov chain maintain the same properties as a standard Markov chain to express the Probability density in t.

How to express the probability of state k? Is there any relevant literature studying this issue?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In that case a process $Y_n = (X_n, X_{n-1})$ is a classic Markov chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above chain is basically still a Markov chain. Consider the sequence
$$ Z_t:=\left(\begin{array}1 X_t\\X_{t-1}\end{array}\right). $$
I assume that the chain $X_t$ is parametrized by $t\geq 0$. This is a vector-valued sequence of random variables. Since $X_t$ ‘depends’ on the previous two states, $Z_t$ depends only on $Z_{t-1}$ (I am using this word to describe the Markov property, I think you get what I mean because you also used that).

With this definition, $Z_0$ is not defined. If $X_0$ and $X_1$ are any two random variables with no particular relation one with the other (or if they are constant, etc.), you simply start your chain with $Z_1$ as your initial state and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it. Vectors are indeed useful. I can see that $X_t$ depends on $Z_{t-1}$, but $X_{t-1}$ depends on $X_{t-2}$ and $X_{t-3}$ which we denote as $Z_{t-2}$. In that case,  the second component of $Z_t$ does not maintain classic Markovicity.

Comment: But $X_{t-1}$ is also the first component of $Z_{t-1}$ so it depends (trivially) only on $Z_{t-1}$, this is why I do this